# Web Api already defines a member called 'Get' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/companies/{company_id}/users/{user_id}
    public object Get(int company_id, int user_id)
    {
       ...
    }

    // GET api/companies/{company_id}/plants/{plant_id}/users
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(int company_id, int plant_id)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The first method should return a single user part of a company
The second method should return a list users part of a company and a plant

**ERROR** Type '...' already defines a member called 'Get' with the same parameter types

Is it possible to avoid Web Api to interpret the second Get as a redefinition?

if looked at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API 
where in scenario 3 uses [HttpGet("...")]notations

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet("actors/{actorId}/movies")]
    public Movie Get(int actorId) { }
    [HttpGet("directors/{directorId}/movies")]
    public Movie Get(int directorId) { }
}
```

but in my case 
[HttpGet(...)] 
**ERROR** 'System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: It's not "web api" complaining. It should be the C# compiler complaining. You can't have two methods with the same name, in the same class, with the same parameter types. Return types play no part in overload resolution.

Comment: (That scenario 3 example also appears to be wrong, for exactly the same reason, as is pointed out by the first comment below the article)

Comment: I was hoping to let know C# they were actually two different overload methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to name your get functions:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/companies/GetByUser/{company_id}/{user_id}
    public object GetByUser(int company_id, int user_id)
    {
       ...
    }

    // GET api/companies/GetByPlanet/{company_id}/{plant_id}
    public IEnumerable<object> GetByPlanet(int company_id, int plant_id)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```